# I'm a bit confused about the uses of adv and Adj when describing things

Tags: grammar

When describing things with only 1 word or short sentence, do I use adv or adj?

E.g

> 1. I used to do an IELTS test, but my score is unofficial, just a mock test (whole sentence)

If I only want to mention my score is unofficial, do I use "But unofficial", or "But unofficially"?

> 2. The view is so beautiful (whole sentence)

Short form: "Wow, so beautiful" OR "wow, beautifully"

Comment: Can you make your post neater? For example, you should mind the capitalization, spelling, punctuation, etc. I've tried to help you edit it, but I'm not sure whether it's the same as what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

In normal English, you can either ***be beautiful*** (*She **is** beautiful* - where ***to be*** is a [***copula***](https://linguapress.com/grammar/to-be.htm) verb), or ***[verb] beautifully*** *(You **sing** beautifully, He **writes** beautifully,...)*.

You can (just about) ***live** beautifully*, but you can't ***be** beautifully*. And you can only do things like ***write** beautiful* or [***dress** beautiful*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22she%20dresses%20beautiful%22) in "non-standard" dialectal contexts (such as AAVE).

The first three written instances of ***she dresses beautiful*** returned by Google Books in the above link are all "educational" publications, pointing out that the construction is "invalid, non-standard".

---

Hence...

> *I **did** an IELTS test **unofficially***...
> *...and my IELTS score **is unofficial***

> *The view from your window **is beautiful***...
> *...and your photograph **captures** the view **beautifully***

Answer (score 0):

You use the adjective form.

In each case you are describing the noun, not the verb.